# Browser Copy/Paste the components

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

We are using new clipboard API to implement the browser/operating system wide copy paste.

We have a set of components (Assume it like a flow charts which have connected div) and that is build from a simple json.

Our goal is to implement Copy and paste. We have a underlying JsON in hand, i tried to save the Json file in clipboard.

Now the real problem starts:

1: Copy and Paste is operating system wide, so how can i know that, currently copied element is json and that is what we needed to build the flow. Eg: a user can copy whatever they want, but i only want the data which my system can parse.

2: How generally these type of applications works, for example, on Slack, i copied a formatted markdown message into my clipboard and i pasted the same into a text editor, but i don't see any markdown command on the selected text, but somehow i pasted the same thing in slack, i got the same message which i copied earlier.

Is anyone have done Copy/Paste of components,
Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example for how to do clipboard manipulation. Read up on [paste](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/paste_event) and [copy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/copy_event) events for more detailed info. You could also try to set a different `content-type` for the clipboard data. This is probably how Slack does it: Set one clipboard entry in plain text (without markdown formatting) and one in Markdown.

```js
const input = document.getElementById("testInput");

input.addEventListener("copy", (e) => {
  console.log("copied!");
  e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', JSON.stringify({
    test: "value"
  }));
  e.preventDefault();
});

input.addEventListener("paste", (e) => {
  console.log("pasted!");
  //console.log(e);
  if (e.clipboardData.types[0] == "text/plain") {
    const txt = e.clipboardData.getData('text')
    try {
      const json = JSON.parse(txt);
      // TODO: validate that object has correct keys
      console.log(json);
      e.preventDefault();
      // I added prevent default, since you probably want to have your own logic for rendering the clipboard content
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("text is not JSON parseable: " + txt);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="testInput"></input>
```